# Get DataTable object from HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have a problem where I am trying to access a data table object of a particular HTML element.

I have looked at the docs for JQuery Data Table and am using this example:
https://datatables.net/reference/option/retrieve

This however, does not work. Here is my code in my global file `main.js`:

```
function initTable () {
    return $(".dynamic-table").DataTable({
        "aaSorting": [],
        "scrollY": 530,
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "lengthMenu": [
            [100, 400, 1000, 5000, -1],
            [100, 400, 1000, 5000, "All"]
        ],
        "retrieve": true
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    initTable();
});
```

Now inside of my other file I attempt to retrieve the object:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = initTable();
});
```

This does not retrieve the object but instead it initializes the object again and causes the table to render twice.

[image]

I have also tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $(".dynamic-wide-table").DataTable();
});
```

because I have read some threads saying that a blank initialization will just retrieve the object.

Neither of these solutions work. If anybody knows what I am doing wrong I would greatly appreciate it! Thanks.

Comment: Why do you use "DataTable" instead of "dataTable"? they are not the same, the former instantiates a table, and returns a datatable api reference, while the latter simply instantiates a table

Comment: I'm not sure. Ever since I have implemented datatables I have used `DataTable`. What is the difference?

Comment: @elad.chen it's actualy `dataTable` not `DataTable` or `datatable`. Look at the example, it is case sensitive.

Comment: @Adjit There are two apis one can use when using data tables, one is $.fn.DataTable and $.fn.dataTable They are not the same.

Comment: I would think something else could also be interfering here or your code/screenshot are not in synch as the second set of table filtering options shows as 10 and the code being called does not have 10 as an option in lengthMenu

Answer (score 15):

```
$(".dynamic-wide-table").DataTable();
```

Referencing like the above is the correct way to obtain a Data Tables API reference.

You can test this in the datatables examples https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html and then enter the below JS into your console. You will see it does not redraw the table or create a second table.

```
  var table = $('#example').DataTable()
```

Also see the API docs https://datatables.net/reference/api/ that clearly state this method.

Using the `table` object you can do any datatable operation.

Answer (score 1):

You may use extend ..

```
   $.extend( true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
            "bFilter": true,

        } );
```

Comment: Would you please develop and explain clearly your answer. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

For getting the instance when you have a selector ("#table_id" or ".display-tables" for example):

```
var instance = new $.fn.dataTable.Api( 'selector' );
```

[DataTable.net docs](https://datatables.net/reference/api/)